# CSS2 Selectors and Style override

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="testBlue">
    <span>hello</span>
    <span id="testGreen" class="testGreen">hello2</span>
</div>
```

If I have set in CSS:

```
#testBlue span { color:Blue; }    
.testGreen, #testGreen { color:Green; }
```

How can I override the general style in the second SPAN?

I have tried both id and class selectors but it doesnt override it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS, selectors with higher specificity override selectors that are more general.

In your example you defined a style for a **span inside a div with id = "testBlue"**. This selector is **more specific** than the simple selector for the class or id **testGreen**, so it wins. You just  need a selector more specific than **#testBlue span**, that is not difficult to find:

```
#testBlue span.testGreen {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Some elaboration as to why this works would be good. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: Done adding some argumentation.

Answer (score 5):

Dont use important give it more weight like this

```
#testBlue span { color:Blue; } 
#testblue #testgreen{color:Red}
```

Edit

Ive been taught using !important is bad practice

Certain objects in css have different weight in the decision to apply a rule

See http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

I suppose its not wrong to use important but better practice to use weighting for specicifity

Comment: sorry color:Green should be color:red

Comment: Well, edit your post then. Explain why !important is sub-optimal and I'll up-vote this.

Comment: You still forgot to change the color to "red".

Comment: Yes it does, after Allen has made a small correction to his code.

Answer (score 3):

```
#testGreen { color: red !important;}
```

or

```
.testGreen { color: red !important;}
```

Either will override the inherited rule, because `!important` puts more weight to one side of an an otherwise equal decision.

Comment: Your solution worked and I upvoted it, thanks! I accepted the one given by @alexmeia because to me it feels simpler.

Comment: I also think his solution is nicer. You should up-vote him as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
span#testGreen
{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use selector

```
#testBlue * { color:Blue; }
```

Comment: Why? Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the standard CSS DOM selectors (so you can drop the class names) like this:

```
#testblue > span:first-child + span{}
```

testblue span THAT IS DIRECT DESCENDANT && FIRST-CHILD NEXT SIBLING span